# How can I override facter's os facts during local testing on a different operating system?

Tags: puppet, read-eval-print-loop, hiera, facter, pdk

### Environment

I am currently using Puppet 6.21.1 on Ruby 2.7.4 with PDK 2.3.0 (mostly for linting and launching the Puppet console as a REPL). The OS is macOS Monetery. If it matters, I'm running Ruby under RVM 1.29.12-next with a module-specific gemset.

### Objective

I'm trying to test some Hiera lookups within a module on a macOS machine, and am trying to override the `kernel`, `os`, and `osfamily` facts returned on the development box by facter.

*[See notes on the X/Y problem at the bottom of the post.]*

### What I've Tried

I have tried using the *FACTERLIB* environment variable, various individually-set *FACTER_* environment variables, and a custom facts directory with the `facter --custom-dir` flag. While I have limited success my setting top-level variables with individual `FACTER_` prefixed environment variables, I can't seem to get facter to return a defined Hash for `facter os` that I copied from a Debian or Ubuntu host, which is what I'm currently trying to do for reasons I touch on below.

My current fact override looks like this:

```rb
# ${module_repository?}/.myfacts/os.rb

Facter.add(:os) do
  confine :kernal => 'Darwin'
  has_weight = 1_000

  setcode do
    {
      architecture => 'amd64',
      distro => {
        codename => 'focal',
        description => 'Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS',
        id => 'Ubuntu',
        release => {
          full => '20.04',
          major => '20.04',
        },
      },
      family => 'Debian',
      hardware => 'x86_64',
      name => 'Ubuntu',
      release => {
        full => '20.04',
        major => '20.04',
      },
      selinux => {
        enabled => false,
      },
    }
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, calling `facter --custom-dir=".myfacts" facter os` from within the module's top-level directory results in the standard facts (give or take the top-level facter element, which doesn't appear in the output when not running overrides) for macOS Monterey:

```rb
facter => 
os => {
  architecture => "x86_64",
  family => "Darwin",
  hardware => "x86_64",
  macosx => {
    build => "21A559",
    product => "macOS",
    version => {
      full => "12.0.1",
      major => "12",
      minor => "0",
      patch => "1"
    }
  },
  name => "Darwin",
  release => {
    full => "21.1.0",
    major => "21",
    minor => "1"
  }
}
```

### Both the X and the Y in my X/Y Problem

How can I get facter to report itself as a Debian-family Ubuntu system so that I can properly test my Hiera v5 lookups under `${module_respository?}/data/os/Debian.yaml` from `PDK console` on my non-Puppetized Darwin development system?

Comment: I'm wondering why ? You can create different facts and use those in your module. You can also generate static facts in `/etc/puppetlabs/facter/facts.d/<anyname>.yaml`. The convention is that static facts overwrite dynamic facts.

Comment: @azbarcea Because I'm doing *local* testing without a Puppetmaster, and want to test the Hiera data in my local module rather than on the Puppetmaster. That's really kind of the whole point.

Comment: To do local testing, I recommend using [specserver](https://serverspec.org/), and if you have a docker environment and what to have end-to-end testing on the real platform, I recommend using (litmus](https://puppet.com/blog/litmus-new-module-acceptance-testing-tool/). On `specserver` you end-up having something like: `let(:osfamilyname) { 'Debian' }`. You can do this for any facts (built-in or custom)

Comment: What kind of tests are you writing?  PDK has built-in support for creating and running spec tests of the catalog-building process.  These will test for every OS supported by your module, as recorded in the module metadata, in part by presenting an appropriate set of OS-specific facts to the catalog builder.  It sounds like you are trying to roll your own version of that, instead of using the facilities that are already available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`FACTER_<fact_name>=<fact_value> puppet agent -t ...`

See also: https://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/override-a-facter-fact.html

Answer (score 0):

Using rspec-puppet is the best path forward in my experience. I too haven't had luck injecting facts (in any reliable way) to override... However, rspec-puppet can test with any pre-determined set of facts locally, or from various canned factsets. Give [it](https://rspec-puppet.com/tutorial/) a shot.